# Firebase Promises and retun values

Tags: firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to match infos from different places and construct the response for this function in firebase.
The problem is the return statements, they return an unexpected jSON

I need to fetch a match from the matchId, the match contains a list of playersId.
I need to get all the profiles for those players and return them.

Current code:

```
exports.getUsersForMatch = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    matchId = data.matchId;
    return store.collection('match').doc(matchId).get().then(doc => {
        return doc.data().playersid;
    }).then(playersId => {
        return combineUsers(playersId)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        throw err;

    });
});

function combineUsers(playersId) {
    users = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < playersId.length; i++) {
        user = getUser(playersId[i])
        users.push(user);
    }
    return Promise.all(users)
}

function getUser(userID) {
    return store.collection('user').doc(userID).get().then(user => {
        return user;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        throw err;
    });
}
```

From the app side i receive this:

```
[{
    "_createTime": {
        "_nanoseconds": 853961000,
        "_seconds": 1563270188
    },
    "_fieldsProto": {
        "number": {
            "valueType": "integerValue",
            "integerValue": "1"
        },
        "id": {
            "stringValue": "SFWxifRwJ9crta4lpPUbLq5d34v1",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        },
        "point ": {
            "valueType": "integerValue",
            "integerValue": "0"
        }
    },
    "_ref": {
        "_firestore": {
            "_clientPool": {
                "clientFactory": {},
                "concurrentOperationLimit": 100,
                "activeClients": {}
            },
            "_settings": {
                "firebaseVersion": "8.2.0",
                "libName": "gccl",
                "projectId": "***",
                "libVersion": "2.2.4 fire/8.2.0"
            },
            "_lastSuccessfulRequest": 1563698812565,
            "_settingsFrozen": true,
            "_serializer": {
                "timestampsInSnapshots": true,
                "createReference": {}
            },
            "_preferTransactions": true,
            "_projectId": "football-5290b"
        },
        "_path": {
            "databaseId": "(default)",
            "_projectId": "***"
            "segments": ["user", "SFWxifRwJ9crta4lpPUbLq5d34v1"]
        }
    },
    "_serializer": {
        "timestampsInSnapshots": true,
        "createReference": {}
    },
    "_readTime": {
        "_nanoseconds": 491530000,
        "_seconds": 1563698812
    },
    "_updateTime": {
        "_nanoseconds": 179584000,
        "_seconds": 1563304513
    }
}, {
    "_createTime": {
        "_nanoseconds": 759742000,
        "_seconds": 1563288148
    },
    "_fieldsProto": {
        "number": {
            "valueType": "integerValue",
            "integerValue": "2"
        },
        "id": {
            "stringValue": "S28K3KDrwYPjVHvSOHu29umCGra2",
            "valueType": "stringValue"
        },
        "point ": {
            "valueType": "integerValue",
            "integerValue": "0"
        }
    },
    "_ref": {
        "_firestore": {
            "_clientPool": {
                "clientFactory": {},
                "concurrentOperationLimit": 100,
                "activeClients": {}
            },
            "_settings": {
                "firebaseVersion": "8.2.0",
                "libName": "gccl",
            "_projectId": "***"
                "libVersion": "2.2.4 fire/8.2.0"
            },
            "_lastSuccessfulRequest": 1563698812565,
            "_settingsFrozen": true,
            "_serializer": {
                "timestampsInSnapshots": true,
                "createReference": {}
            },
            "_preferTransactions": true,
            "_projectId": "***"
        },
        "_path": {
            "databaseId": "(default)",
            "_projectId": "***"
            "segments": ["user", "S28K3KDrwYPjVHvSOHu29umCGra2"]
        }
    },
    "_serializer": {
        "timestampsInSnapshots": true,
        "createReference": {}
    },
    "_readTime": {
        "_nanoseconds": 495247000,
        "_seconds": 1563698812
    },
    "_updateTime": {
        "_nanoseconds": 480467000,
        "_seconds": 1563304509
    }
}]
```

Comment: "*The problem is the return statements, they return promises*" - no, that's not a problem, that is exactly how it is supposed to work. A function **cannot** synchronously wait for a promise to be fulfilled.

Comment: Apart from the [missing variable declarations](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), your code seems to work just fine?

Comment: Moreover it will boil down to about one third the volume of code.

Comment: Not clear whats going wrong. What is the error/expected and real result? And you can force the function to work in a synchronous way with async&await.

Comment: Edited the question to provide a better overview on the problem

Comment: So what exactly is unexpected about the JSON, what did you expect instead? Do you maybe need to call `.data()` on each `user` document that you got, similar to how you did it for the match `doc`s?

Comment: I would like to return the following json:
[
{user1},
{user2}]